# join structs in c++?

Tags: c++, networking, struct

I'm trying to create an ethernet packet plus TCP/IP payload, for that I've create three structs as follows: ethernet struct, tcp struct and ip struct all these structs are filled with valid information but I don't know what I need to do now, I need join the spared structs into a plain struct (such as an array) since I want to inject the constructed packet and all bits need to be consecutive.

Comment: I have no clue what you're actually asking about. Please provide a minimal code example, for what you're actually trying, into your question to elaborate!

Comment: The title says "Join structs in c++" or "append structs in c++ into a BYTE array"  in this sense is clear for me despite of what is for.

Answer (score 2):

Define a new class, make these three structs its instance variables, code setters and getters for the class. You may want to pay attention to const correctness when writing getters - mark getters with const keyword.

```
struct EthStruct1
{
     // ...
};
struct EthStruct2
{
     // ...
};
struct EthStruct3
{
    // ...
}

class newClass
{
public :
     newClass(){}
     ~newClass(){}

     // Add functions to get and set values in A. Mark getters with const for immutability of receiver
     // Add functions to get and set values in B. Mark getters with const for immutability of receiver
     // Add functions to get and set values in C. Mark getters with const for immutability of receiver
private:  
     EthStruct1 A;
     EthStruct2 B;
     EthStruct3 C;
};
```

Comment: What kind of answer is this please?!? Can you come to a point (working code sample), besides your overly broad points. Answering an unclear question shouldn't result in a more unclear answer on SO!

Comment: This is a clear answer to anyone who knows C++.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a byte array whose size is the sum of the sizes of the three structs. Then copy the raw bytes of each struct into the array where needed.  Then use the array as needed.

```
struct ethernet
{
    ...
};

struct tcp
{
    ...
};

struct ip
{
    ...
};

ethernet e;
tcp t;
ip i;

unsigned char arr[sizeof(e)+sizeof(t)+sizeof(i)];
memcpy(&arr[0], &e, sizeof(e)];
memcpy(&arr[sizeof(e)], &t, sizeof(t)];
memcpy(&arr[sizeof(e)+sizeof(t)], &i, sizeof(i)];
```

Alternatively:

```
struct ethernet
{
    ...
};

struct tcp
{
    ...
};

struct ip
{
    ...
};

struct pkt
{
    ethernet e;
    tcp t;
    ip i;
};

ethernet e;
tcp t;
ip i;

unsigned char arr[sizeof(pkt)];
pkt *p = (pkt) &arr[0];
p->e = e;
p->t = t;
p->i = i;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your first answer helped me to create a WINBIO_BIR record for Windows Biometric Framework because I cannot create a new parent struct.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `union` when converting structures to byte arrays. Be sure your compiler is using single-byte structure alignment... for the Windows compiler I know you can use `#pragma pack(push,1)` to start that and `#pragma pack(pop)` to terminate. I will use this way in my example.

```
#pragma pack(push,1) // start single-byte struct alignment
struct EthernetInfo
{
    // data here
};
struct TCPInfo
{
    // data here
};
struct IPInfo
{
    // data here
};

union Packet
{
    struct {
        struct EthernetInfo ethernetInfo;
        struct TCPInfo      tcpInfo;
        struct IPInfo       ipInfo;
    } AsPacket;
    unsigned char AsBytes[sizeof(EthernetInfo) + sizeof(TCPInfo) + sizeof(IPInfo)];
};
#pragma pack(pop) // revert to whatever struct alignment was in use before
```